# Invalid Request - Laravel with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm working with Laravel and when I try to use a requisition with Ajax, my terminal in VS Code shows this message (don't show any message in console):

```
[Fri May 28 11:03:41 2021] 127.0.0.1:57828 Invalid request (Foi for�ado o cancelamento de uma conex�o existente pelo host remoto.)
```

I have a Ajax code like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/comercial/relacoes/clientes/entrega-assinatura",
        data: {
            '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            'id_contato': "{{ $contato_id }}",
            'assinatura_gerente': $('#ass-gerente').attr('src'),
            'assinatura_cliente': $('#ass-cliente').attr('src'),
            'observacao': $('#observacoes').val(),
            'user_update': $('#input-hidden').val(),
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.errors)
            {
                swal('Oops!', display_errors(response.errors), 'error');
                btn_enable(btn, btn_text);
            }
            else {
                swal_redirect('Ok!', response, 'success');
                console.log(response);
                btn_enable(btn, btn_text);
                window.open('/comercial/relacoes/clientes/ae2112f247772ea3e98aef75770435e6', '_self');
            }
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            btn_enable(btn, btn_text);
        }
    });
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/relacoes/clientes/entrega-assinatura', 'Modules\Comercial\ComercialReqController@entrega_assinatura');
```

But there's a inconclusive point: this error shows sometimes, not always... but just with this route.

Comment: I don't know any Portuguese but `"brindes-cliente"` is not `'/relacoes/clientes/entrega-assinatura'`.

Comment: set the `dataType: json` and check it out if works

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. The Ajax was doesn't correct, but now is the correct

Comment: @AliQorbani do not worked

Answer (score 0):

You should replace
url: "/relacoes/clientes/entrega-assinatura"
with
url: "/comercial/relacoes/clientes/entrega-assinatura"